What is the optimal way of increasing the number of pullups I do?
I am trying to reduce the time spent in the gym while also keeping some goals in mind from which the main one I can think of is getting stronger in pull ups. My split is push-pull-legs but only once a week each. Is it enough to do 4-5 sets of pull ups to failure in my pull day? Should I try weighted pull ups instead considering that my reps in those sets usually look something like 10-9-8-8-6? Or should I take 10-15 minutes off a rest day to do some sets of normal pullups because doing it twice a week makes a huge difference?

If you just want to reduce time in the gym, superset them with something that uses different muscles (I superset pull ups and dips - assisted in my case and they are the same machine).  But then I prefer something more like full-body workouts rather than PPL, as it means to can work some muscle groups more frequently than others.

To do more pull-ups, you have to do... more pull-ups. Doing 5 sets to failure is one way to do it. However, from my own experience, it's worth doing the first 4 sets not to failure but as some fixed number and only do the last set to failure. This will likely increase the total number of pull-ups you do since it's much easier to pull up if your previous set wasn't a to-failure one. I wouldn't go for weighted pull-ups until you get to sets of 20+ pull-ups.
Doing that 1 day per week is fine, but the progress will be quite slow. Try switching to 2 or 3 sessions per week for a more steady and visible progress.

As a fitness coach my favorite schedule for three days a week of workout is full body. Try to add at the end of your workout exercises to strengthen your grip. I think one exercise would be enough, about 2-3 sets, doesn't matter which one. I hope this helps.

It isn’t clear that this addresses the question. The question doesn’t indicate grip being an issue, and your answer does t make it clear that extra grip exercises have any transfer to pull-ups.

My interpretation was that it is better to work those muscle groups more often, but fewer sets.  This fits with my (non-expert) understanding that it is the overload (hence failure) and recovery time that matters, rather than how many sets/reps per se?
